# SESSION_USERNAME cannot be resolved or is not a field

Tags: java, jsp, model-view-controller

I am using JSP and calling classes in the file.
Here is my source code.

```
<%@ page import="abc.common.Constants" %>
<%@ page import="abc.util.SessionHandler" %>
<%
if (!SessionHandler.isAliveSession(request)
||  StringUtils.isBlank(SessionHandler.getSessionValue(request, 
Constants.SESSION_USERNAME))) {
    response.sendRedirect("/login.jsp");
}
%>
```

The error message is below.
**JBWEB004060: An error occurred at line: 13 in the jsp file: /WEB-INF/view/home.jsp
SESSION_USERNAME cannot be resolved or is not a field**

There is no error in this part, "SessionHandler.isAliveSession(request)".
When I use an IDE, there is no error and building this war was ok.
When I run the jsp, the error happened.

It could call isAliveSession(), but why there is an error at 'SESSION_USERNAME'?
What did I miss?

Comment: Is the `Constants` class available on runtime? I.e. is there `WEB-INF/classes/abc/common/Constants.class` file in your webapp, or is it packed in a JAR file in the `WEB-INF/lib` folder?

Comment: Yes, in war file, all classes are under WEB-INF/classes. The weird thing is why only some of things are not resolved.

Comment: Is `SESSION_USERNAME` a field that actually exists in the `Constants`class, is it `static` and is it `public`?

Comment: Yes,public static final String SESSION_USERNAME = "user";  Can I call static variable in jsp? 'isAliveSession() is static method.